# How to use p value to determine statistical significance of change in student test scores.

Tags: statistics

I have around 100 students who have all sat 3 exams and are about to sit another. Since their last exam I have made changes to my instruction and I want to determine if any changes in student scores is statistically significant.

I took one statistics class in university, but I can't remember exactly how to calculate the p values, assuming that's the best way to determine statistical significance.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any test that simply looks at just the students who underwent the change in instruction isn't really valid. It would need to be compared with a before and after test of a similar number of students who didn't receive a change in instruction (a control group). Otherwise, how do you know the test wasn't simply easier? There are also other criteria for a valid test like randomly assigning treatment and control groups, double blind testing where the students and the graders don't know which group is which.

You could then run a test comparing a difference in means between the two groups. Take the mean and standard deviation of each groups' difference in scores and run a $2$ sample t-test.

$$t = \frac{\bar x_1 - \bar x_2}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{s^2_2}{n_2}}}$$

Where $\bar x$ is the mean of the difference in scores from before and after modified instruction tests, $s$ is the standard deviation of the differences and $n$ is the sample size.

Then look at a t-table to determine a p-value and compare it with an appropriate level of significance $(.05)$. A p-value less than $.05$ would be statistically significant.